# IronPython's standard libraries in compiled IronPython's GUI Application

Tags: ironpython

Hi all,
first time to ask here, usually everything i need is already answered here, but this one really is bugging me and i can't find the answer *yet*

I'm developing an IronPython (ver 2.7.2.1) GUI App in Windows 7 64 bit with Visual Studio 2010. I've succesfully compiled the whole app, but i found a *strange* behavior when calling `sys.version` from the compiled `.exe` app.
Here is the part that do the calling:

```
clr.AddReference("StdLib")
import sys
from platform import python_version_tuple
print sys.version
print sys.path
```

And here is the output of calling the main script of path with `ipy.exe`:

> D:\VisualStudioSolutions\MarketingAppSolution\MarketingApp>ipy MarketingApp.py
>   2.7.2 (IronPython 2.7.2.1 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.239 (32-bit))
>   ['D:\VisualStudioSolutions\MarketingAppSolution\MarketingApp'..]

And here is the output of calling the compiled `.exe` app:

```
> D:\VisualStudioSolutions\MarketingAppSolution\MarketingApp>out\MarketingApp.exe
> 2.7.2 ()
> ['.', 'D:\\VisualStudioSolutions\\MarketingAppSolution\\MarketingApp\\out\\Lib', 'D:\\VisualStudioSolutions\\MarketingAppSolution\\Mar
ketingApp\\out\\DLLs']
> failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.2 ()'
```

The `StdLib` in `clr.AddReference("StdLib")` is the clr import of my compiled dll of IronPython's standard library.
And as you can see that if i called `python_version_tuple` function of `platform` module of IronPython from within compiled app, it caused `failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.2 ()'` error.

So, what am i doing wrong in compilation process?
How should i integrate the IronPython's standard libraries to distribute them along with my application?
Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [an IronPython Issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/31736) with user-created engines. Basically, IronPython expected hosts to set the version variables on the engine. The executable created by `pyc.py` is a host, and it does not set those variables.

This will be properly fixed in 2.7.4, but that won't be out for a few months. In the meantime, you can manually set `sys.version` to match the version string you want before importing from platform.

```
import sys
if sys.version == '2.7.2 ()':
    sys.version = '2.7.2 (IronPython 2.7.2.1 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.239 (32-bit))'
```